# Floppy / Brushless DC motor speed regulation

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

I have a non working TEAC FD-235f 161-U, which is a rather rare (nowadays) 3-1/2" Amiga floppy drive.

A cap had leaked over the PCB and eaten away at the traces. I jumper wired the broken traces and replaced the cap with a through hole 4,7µF electrolytic cap.
https://imgur.com/a/zD79Z

I know its not pretty but its the best I could pull off with my shaky hands.

I triple checked the new connections and they are ok with no solder bridges on the little pins or anything.

The drive is still not reading any disks. When inserting a disk, **the flywheel spins up to 800rpm (while it should be exactly 300)** and the head is clicking a few times as if it was reading, but it stops and goes back to 1.3 boot screen.

My multimeter is giving me a reading of 13,5hz at the hall sensors output pin, which would equal something around 800rpm.

I noticed the cap I replaced had the wrong value, the original one had 10μF. Though replacing it with a correct one didn't do anything to the rotation speed.
I even tried a different ceramic resonator from a similar drive, and also removed the VCC from the hall sensor to see what happens. Nothing, rpm stayed the same.

I wonder if the hall sensor is involved in speed regulation at all.
Big problem is that I cannot remove the flywheel to see where the motor is powered from, because the screwhead is b0rked but still firmly attached.

I can confirm the hall sensor is working properly (as is my multimeter, I just did an aural RPM check by duct taping something to the flywheel which produces one click per revolution, recorded that and measured the time between clicks. 13,5hz is correct, the drive is really spinning at around 800-810 rpm. Darnit

Neither my meter nor my newly aquired scope is able to verify the correct operation of the resonators (because of limited bandwidth), which should generate a signal of one Mhz for 300rpm. Since two resonators produce the same result I can only assume - with my limited to non existant knowledge of brushless dc motors - that the controller IC must have gone bad. I dont have a similar one or I'd just swap and test.

Sorry for this wall of text. So my question is, what could be the possible causes of a brushless DC motor exceeding the nominal RPM of 300 by 500?

Could it be that it has MORE hall sensors below the flywheel that I can't get at (yet?)? Wouldn't the motor not move at all if the controller would have gone bad?
This tech is so old that I can't find schematics for this device, not even datasheets for the controller IC of the motor or the resonator.

Comment: The speed is software controlled by reading the bit speed on the disc. If it cannot read this data it may run at full speed trying to find readable data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if the hall sensor is involved in speed regulation at all.

It's not. That hall sensor is only used to generate the 'index' pulse which indicates the start of the track. It produces one pulse per revolution.

> Could it be that it has MORE hall sensors below the flywheel

Yes. It will probably have 3 hall sensors between the coils. If any of these sensors weren't working the motor probably wouldn't run because the commutation sequence would be wrong.

It also has an 'FG' (frequency generator) coil, which is a zig-zag track on the PCB under the outer edge of the rotor. If the FG track was broken the motor would speed up trying to match the reference speed setting, which is the symptom you have.

I suspect that either the FG track is corroded near the capacitor, or there is something wrong with your repair (broken track, bad joint, short) which is affecting the FG circuit.

Example FDD spindle motor with rotor removed:-

[image]

Example FDD controller speed control circuit ([BA6486FS](http://rtellason.com/chipdata/ba6486.pdf)):-
[image]

> I cannot remove the flywheel to see where the motor is powered from,
>   because the screwhead is b0rked but still firmly attached.

Try softening the glue with a soldering iron, then grab the outside of the screwhead with sidecutters and turn it. Note that this screw may have a left-hand thread!

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the missing piece of the puzzle. It looks like I have to drill out the screw, I tried my best but couldn't remove it, despite the glue came off easily.

Comment: Did you try unscrewing it clockwise?

Comment: Yes I did. I completely removed the glue first, then tried both directions, but my tool always slipped on the worn notches. I guess someone must have tried to get it off before me. Sidecutters were slipping off even more easily in both directions too. I drilled it out now. You were totally right, the FG trace is broken.